# No 'print' output when using yield?

Tags: python

I am implementing a web scraper using the scrapy framework.  In order to implement pipeline, `yield` is necessary when parsing the response from the scraper.  It seems to me that when using `yield` at the end of a function, all output from `print` statements is suppressed and replaced by the generator object.

```
def testFunc(arg1):
    print arg1
    yield arg1

testFunc('This does not print.')
```

Results in:

```
In [7]: testFunc('Will this print?')
Out[7]: <generator object testFunc at 0x10d636d20>
```

Simply commenting the `yield` restores the `print` call:

```
def testFunc(arg1):
    print arg1
```

Results in:

```
In [10]: testFunc('Will this print?')
Will this print?
```

How do I maintain `print` output when using `yield`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Comment: Despite all my reading on the "yield" keyword, and understanding that what was actually yield-ed is a generator that requires iteration, it wasn't clear that everything in the body was held for execution until iteration occurred.  @Cubemaster describes as a "byproduct" and that makes sense.  Perhaps this specific question will help others by singling out this particular byproduct since it is readily observable when working with yield.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The print statements will be executed whenever the generator is iterated over. If you just want to see what the iterator prints, you can call it in a list comprehension without saving the result.

```
def testFunc(arg1):
    print arg1
    yield arg1

>>> [_ for _ in testFunc(1)]
1
[1]
```

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: Or just `list(testFunc(1))`.

Answer (score 7):

*Calling* a generator function as in `testFunc(1)` simply creates a generator instance; it does not run the body of the code.  Generators are iterators, so you can pass them to `next()`.  In the case of Generators, the action of its `__next__()` is essentially to run up to the next `yield` statement and return the yielded value.  So you can do things like:

```
>>> gen = testFunc(1)
>>> next(gen)
Will this print?
1
```

or, as others have noted, you can loop over it (though this is not necessary if you want to just yield one value).

When you define a generator, you can almost think of calling a generator as creating an instance of some class that implements a very specific state machine that works as an iterator.  To be clear, that's not actually *how* it works, but it can be written equivalently that way.  Generators are a much more elegant way to do this in most cases, however.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone gave the answer to "How do I maintain print output when using yield?" from the perspective of the programmer writing the function.

Here it is:

```
def testFunc(arg1):
    print(arg1)
    def foo():
         yield arg1
    return foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

@bphi beat me to the answer, but here is some elaboration on why his solution works:

Any time a `yield` is included in a function, the rest of the code in that body will not run until the generator created by the `yield` is used. This is just a byproduct of how `yield` works in python. If you ever want to execute code in the same function as you have a `yield`, just stick it in an empty `for` loop, like bphi demonstrated