# python- yield and raise exception

Tags: python, exception, generator

I am trying to write a function that yields two variables and also raises an exception based on a condition.
Here is a minimal example:

```
def func():
  var1 = 0
  var2 = 1
  yield var1, var2
  if not var1 > var2:
    raise Exception(var1,var2)
var1, var2 = (1,1)
var1,var2 = func()
```

This structure currently doesn't yield var1, var2 and raises an exception.
I need it to yield and raise an exception within this function itself so that other modules can directly use this function without additional code.
If the yield statement is not a good idea then what is?

tried - `[_ for _ in func()]` but var1 and var2 value doesn't change as expected from yield. 
tried - `var1, var2 = next(func())` this yields but doesnt raise an exception.

Comment: what kind of `Exception` do you raise? can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: why should the conditional line be checked if you're yielding before it? Do you need to use yield for this problem?

Comment: I am sorry I understood the issue wrong due to my initialization and test cases being the same. Please check the edit I will do on the question.

Comment: This is weird. I had expected execution to pause after the `yield` so that the `raise` would not be executed, but that appears not to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate to execute the exception. Following minimal code indeed raises exception.

```
def func(a,b):
    #..do something...
    yield a, b
    if a!=b:
        raise Exception(a,b)

[_ for _ in func(1,2)]
```

This is related to [No 'print' output when using yield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330513/no-print-output-when-using-yield)

In particular quoting from one answer there `"Calling a generator function as in testFunc(1) simply creates a generator instance; it does not run the body of the code."`

**EDIT**
Following illustrates the solution. This is also from above quoted thread.

```
def func(a,b):
  #..do something...
  for i in range(10):
    a+=1
    yield a, b
    if a>3:
      raise Exception(a,b)

gen=func(1,2)
next(gen) # returns (2,2)
next(gen) # returns (3,2)
next(gen) # return (4,2)
next(gen) # returns Exception. As expected
```

If you do `next(func())` as you mention in your edit, new generator is created every time you call `next(func())`. Instead, as illustrated above, instantiate it first and then call several times.

Community Wiki as related question and cannot add this in comment.

Comment: Yes, it does but how to access a and b that are yielded?

Comment: From your solution value of a and b remains the same. i.e the yield hasn't actually returned the variables. I want the variables from the yield and also an exception to be thrown.

Comment: @SharvariGc does this solve what you want? It is raising exception as you want.

Comment: `if not a==b` instead of `if a!=b`?

Comment: @Mark Ransom  They are same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026754/python-if-not-vs-if

Comment: @Dinesh yes they're the same, but I question it as a matter of style. You should always prefer the simpler expression.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so couple of issues to resolve here first.
1. Unpacking does not work on individual values, it tries to exhaust the iterable and unpack everything at once.

```
def func():
#    ..do something...
    yield 1, 2
    yield 3
    yield 4

a, b = func() #ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
a, b, c, d = func() #ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
a, b, c = func() #Works
print(a) # (1,2)
```

2.Yield stops the execution wherever encountered.

```
def func():
    yield 1, 2
    raise Exception

func_gen = func()
print(func_gen) #<generator object func at 0x000000ACB5A5EBF8>
val1, val2 = next(func_gen) #assigns values
next(func_gen) #raises exception only on next pass
```

3.A compromise has to be made (this should answer what you asked)

```
func_gen = func()
print(func_gen) #<generator object func at 0x000000ACB5A5EBF8>
for _ in func_gen:
    res = _
#raises Exception but res = (1, 2)
```

4.A suggestion instead (please do not use exceptions, it is really a job for if-conditions)

```
def func():
  var1 = 0
  var2 = 1
  flag = not var1 > var2
  yield var1, var2, flag #just add a flag during yield
  #instead of your exception
#  if not var1 > var2:
#    raise Exception(var1,var2)  
  #stuff
  yield 'something else'
func_gen = func()
print(func_gen) #<generator object func at 0x000000ACB5A5EBF8>
for _ in func_gen:
    res = _
    *values, flag = res
    if flag:
        break
var1,var2 = values #0, 1
```

5. Last but not least, make sure you really need the yield, as it stands, i suspect the function is both tough to read and perhaps deserves breaking into smaller modules. I highly recommend taking a second look at the code, and consider breaking it further if possible.